# AirFlow DAG Get stuck in running state

Tags: airflow

I created a dag and scheduled it on a daily basis.
It gets queued every day but tasks don't actually run.
This problem already raised in the past [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507252/example-dag-gets-stuck-in-running-state-indefinitely) but the answers didn't help me so it seems there is another problem.

My code is shared below. I replaced the SQL of task t2 with a comment. 
Each one of the tasks runs successfully when I run them separately on CLI using "airflow test...".

Can you explain what should be done to make the DAG run?
Thanks!

This is the DAG code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator



default_args = {
    'owner' : 'me',
    'depends_on_past' : 'true',
    'start_date' : datetime(2018, 06, 25),
    'email' : ['myemail@moovit.com'],
    'email_on_failure':True,
    'email_on_retry':False,
    'retries' : 2,
    'retry_delay' : timedelta(minutes=5)
}


dag = DAG('my_agg_table',
default_args = default_args,
schedule_interval = "30 4 * * *"
)



t1 = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bq_delete_my_agg_table',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    allow_large_results=True,
    bql='''
    delete `my_project.agg.my_agg_table`
    where date = '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -1)}}'
    ''',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bq_insert_my_agg_table',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    allow_large_results=True,
    bql='''
    #standardSQL
    Select ... the query continue here.....
    ''',    destination_dataset_table='my_project.agg.my_agg_table',
    dag=dag)


t1 >> t2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is usually very easy to find out about the reason why a task is not being run. When in the Airflow web UI:

- select any DAG of interest
- now click on the task
- again, click on `Task Instance Details`
- In the first row there is a panel `Task Instance State`
- In the box `Reason` next to it is the reason why a task is being run - or why a task is being ignored

It usually makes sense to check the first task which is not being executed since I saw you have setup `depends_on_past=True` which can lead to problems if used in a wrong scenario.

More on that here: [Airflow 1.9.0 is queuing but not launching tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks)

Comment: Thanks, tobi6!. Your instructions are very helpful and exposed a possible reason. 
Problem wasn't solved yet because DAG is still stuck but maybe this is for another question.
In the task instance details depends_on_past is now false but an error message saying "depends_on_past is true for this task's DAG, but the previous task instance has not run yet".

Comment: I accepted the answer, thanks. yes, I restarted both the scheduler and the webserver before i added my comment above.

Comment: Strange. You might have to rename the DAG, ex. adding _v1: my_agg_table_v1 and then check again.

Comment: Thanks. Rename worked. at least in the initial run. Hope it will keep running without problems on the daily scheduled run.